# regex: How to search for multiple pattern and append

Tags: regex

I am learning regex because i need them a lot while doing code
I want to add quotation before starting tag of the following html tags:

```
<div>                    
     <button>Save</button>    
     <button>Delete</button>  
     <button>Cancel</button>  
</div>
```

i want that output:

```
'<div>                    
     '<button>Save</button>    
     '<button>Delete</button>  
     '<button>Cancel</button>  
'</div>
```

I try search with this expression : `( <[a-zA-Z] | </d )`

and replace with: `'( <[a-zA-Z]  | </d )`

It did not worked.please help me.

Comment: Do you have specific requirements about what the lines that you prefix with quotes can contain? can they start with something else than HTML tags and what would you want in that case? (i.e. what if the text in a `<button>` spans two lines?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

Find:

```
^(\s*?)(<)
```

Replace:

```
\1'\2
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zGAt4D/3

---

Or in this particular case you can also do:

Find:

```
^(\s*)
```

Replace:

```
\1'
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/zGAt4D/4